# What is this weed?

Tags: botany, species-identification

I first noticed this weed a few years ago, and saw its **long, thin, V-shaped bean-shaped seed pods on meter height plants**.  The pods start out connected together at the far end, but eventually separate into an inverted V.

If I recall, correctly, the thin pods split open to release very small seeds with a sail.

It somewhat resembles milkweed, but is branched, red stemmed and, of course, has these strange pods.

**Location**: My back yard, in Augusta County, in the Shenandoah Valley in Virginia.

[image: Close up of small flowers and pods just beginning to develop]
[image: Most of plant]

Comment: You'd be better off asking for plant identification at https://gardening.stackexchange.com The people there would be more likely to identify it as many requests for plant identification come in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is Hemp Dogbane. The [milkweed "family"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asclepias) has 140 species; all have milky sap. Add red stems, branching, downward-facing pods, and hemp dogbane comes up.

[image]

The flowers are white, not perfectly like common milkweed, and the pods hang down.

[image]

A photo with flowers and pods can be found [here](https://courses.missouristate.edu/pbtrewatha/hemp_dogbane.htm).

Hemp Dogbane is common [throughout the country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apocynum_cannabinum).